# Why the topology generated by $[a,b)$, $a$ and $b$ rational isn't the same as the lower limit one?

Tags: general-topology

I've proved that $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are rationals generate the same topology as the standard one in $\mathbb{R}$, that is, the one generated by $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are reals. I just needed to show that between rationals there are always irrationals and vice versa.

Now, I need to prove that $[a,b)$ with $a,b$ rationals don't generate the same topology as $[a,b)$ where $a,b$ are reals. This topology is the one of the lower limit.

In order to do this, I tried to use a theorem that I just need to show that given a basis element $B_1$ of one topology, such that $x\in B_1$, I just need to find another element $B_2$ of the other topology, such that $x\in B_2\subset B_1$ and vice versa.

Well, for me such inclusions always work. What is the problem?

Comment: Consider $[\sqrt{2}, 2)$. It's open in the topology generated by $[a, b)$ for real $a, b$.

Comment: @AJY if $x\in [\sqrt{2},2)$, I can't find an interval made of rationals contained in this one? That's strange, because this wouldn't work for the $(a,b)$ case then. Could you explain it better to me?

Comment: My point is just that: you can't find one that contains $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Show that if $[a, b)$ is an interval with rational endpoints (in particular, if $a$ is rational), then either $\sqrt{2} \not \in [a, b)$, or $[a, b) \not \subseteq [\sqrt{2} , 2)$.

Comment: To understand why this problem arises for (partially) closed intervals, and not open, let $(r_k)_k be a strictly increasing sequence of reals with limit $r$. Then if $\bigcup_k (0, r_k] = (0, r]$, that would mean $r \in (0, r_k]$ for some $k$. But $r > r_k$, so this can't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real line with the lower-limit topology  is called the Sorgenfrey line, often denoted $S.$ Let $B$ be any base for $S.$ For each $x\in S,$ choose $F(x)\in B$ such that $x\in F(x)\subset [x,x+1)$.  Then $y\ne x\implies F(x)\ne F(y)$ because $\min F(x)=x$ and $\min F(y)=y.$ So $F:S\to B$ is injective. So $B$ is  uncountable. But the set of intervals $[a,b)$ with rational $a, b$ is only countable, so it cannot be a base for $S$.

Remark: The set $\{[a,b):a\in \mathbb Q \land a<b\}$ generates the same topology as $\{[a,b):a,b\in \mathbb Q\}.$